# EF Load Multiple Entity References in one call to Load()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF6.
I have a list of entity items that are detached from a dbContext. I'd like to **explicit** load several of the entities related to them, sometimes with through 2 or 3 levels of navigation.
I'd also like to do all this object graph loading in a single DB call if possible.

If its not possible with explicit loading techniques, I will just re-query the database for those specific item Ids and use eager loading at that point (since there is no other state I need to worry about at this point).

Comment: Could you ask this in more of a question format? I think it would help for me to understand exactly what you are asking for. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicit loading of multiple references/collections on entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013963/explicit-loading-of-multiple-references-collections-on-entity)

Comment: It is not a duplicate question. That one relates to multiple references and this one relates to multiple *levels* of dependencies.