# EF Core: Load related tables in query vs LoadAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF Core, suppose my database model contains a `Patient` entity with related collections like this:

```
public class Patient
{
    // Patient properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public List<Allergy> Allergies { get; set; }
    public List<Medication> Medications { get; set; }
    public List<Symptom> Symptoms { get; set; }
    etc.
}

public class Allergy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    <more properties>

    // Navigation properties
    public int PatientId { get; set; }    // FK to the related Patient
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

In my actual code, I have 8 of these types of relations. If I fetch a Patient and its related collections via LINQ, EF will create a monster query with 8 joins:

```
var qry = from patient in db.Patients
            .Include(p => p.Allergies)
            .Include(p => p.Medications)
            .Include(p => p.Symptoms)
            .Include(<etc.>)
          where patient.Id = <desired Id>
          select patient;
var Patient = await qry.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

My other option is to get the Patient without loading the related collections, then make 8 trips to the database to load the related collections:

```
var qry = from patient in db.Patients
          where patient.Id = <desired Id>
          select patient;
var Patient = await qry.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

await db.Entry(Patient).Collection(p => p.Allergies).LoadAsync();
await db.Entry(Patient).Collection(p => p.Medications).LoadAsync();
await db.Entry(Patient).Collection(p => p.Symptoms).LoadAsync();
etc.
```

**Which strategy is more efficient (faster to execute)? And is there a "happy middle ground" where I load the basic entity with a simple SQL query, then make only a single trip to the database to load all of the desired related collections?**

(I've found SO "answers" like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725190/1637105), that rely on current EF behaviors such as *"This works, because the context will detect that entity you are looking for is loaded and attached already and therefore not create a new one but rather update the old one"*. My problem with those types of solutions is that they may stop working when the EF implementation details change.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1) in EF Core like this:

Just call `.AsSplitQuery()` at the end of the `.Include()` chain.

> EF allows you to specify that a given LINQ query should be split into multiple SQL queries. Instead of JOINs, split queries generate an additional SQL query for each included collection navigation.

```cs
var qry =
    from patient in db.Patients
        .Include(p => p.Allergies)
        .Include(p => p.Medications)
        .Include(p => p.Symptoms)
        .Include(/* etc. */)
        .AsSplitQuery() // <-- add this method call
    where patient.Id = <desired Id>
    select patient;
```